# PHP is there any way to view the generated PHP code

Tags: php

I have a load of dynamic requires within the code and I was wondering if there was a way to see the php code that was generated as in all the diferent php files put together?

Comment: "Generated" ? Just look at the files and there you have it. Or are you writing php dynamically on a file?

Comment: Right there is an auto loader to include the class files dynamicaly, I want to see if it is actually including the class file each time new object is called or if it is only including the file once.

Comment: Well, are you using `require/include` or `require_once/include_once`? Are you getting any error like "Cannot redeclare..."

Comment: It's using require not require_once, I'm trying to prove my point that it should be using require_once to my boss.

Comment: As you cannot declare a class twice(would result in a fatal) and spl_autoload_* and __autoload are aware of loaded classes it doesn't really matter as long as class autoloading is concerned. *_once on the other side has extra costs, when calling. I assume that was your question. Thats not clear however.

Comment: So your question is really about comparison between require and require_once, NOT about how to view "generated PHP code".

Comment: @Ranged: Fair enough, thanks.

Comment: @user11153: Not quite but close.

Comment: @Chris You should edit your question to make clear what you really wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is based on the clarification in the comments of the question:

Autoloading(`spl_autoload_*` or `__autoload`) is only triggered if a class is not yet defined. Using `*_once` has no real advantage here but bears extra cost. PHP makes sure that the class is only loaded once and (if the loader is correctly implemented and no class includes are done by hand) no fatal is thrown.

If you include classes outside of your autoloader by hand you should still use require_once or include_once as you don't know if that class has been autoloaded yet.

I'll also recommend you to stick to a known structure. There are many correctly implemented autoloaders for the [PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) and [PSR-4(recommended)](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) standards out there. They have the advantage to be compatible with external libraries and IDEs.